# Frying then finishing breaded pork chops in the oven

Tags: pork-chops

I want to pan fry first then finish in the oven. For 1" pork chops how long to I bake & at what temperature.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick google search give multiple results.

Most are in the range of oven at 350F, pan fry 3 minutes each side and put in oven for 10 minutes or until around 150F internal temperature.

Comment: Thank you so much I looked but couldn't find the answer